# Finding size of rotated image to match top-line based on angle

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, html5-canvas

(illustration for reference: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wsge0.png)

Code example
https://jsfiddle.net/waaentz/htrqdwjp/9/

```
const width = 1000;
const height = 100;
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
const img = new Image();
const bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(img);
const baseGrid = new createjs.Shape();

const angle = 45; // Is dynamic
const magicScaleFormular = 1.39 // Find scale based on height and angle

img.src = getBase64();
img.addEventListener("load", ()=>{

    stage.addChild(baseGrid, bitmap);
    Object.assign(canvas, {width, height});

    bitmap.regX = (img.width / 2);
    bitmap.regY = img.height;
    bitmap.y = height;
    bitmap.rotation = angle;
    bitmap.scaleY = magicScaleFormular; // <-- scale to match top line

    baseGrid.graphics
        .beginStroke("red")
        .setStrokeStyle(4)
        .moveTo(0,0)
        .lineTo(width, 0)
        .moveTo(0, height)
        .lineTo(width, height)

    stage.update();
    document.body.append(canvas);
});
```

I have an image of 100px height, that needs to grow in size to match a top y-line when being rotated based on it's angle. The top line is currently y0, but could be any cord.

Math.sin and Math.cos seems to make a strange jump in size, so I have stopped trying to use them for this.

When the image is rotated 90 degrees, it would, in theory, grow to an infinite size. This kind of math wizardry goes beyond my mental capacity, and I hope someone smarter in here will show me mercy and let me in on this math secret.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code as well. Thanks.

Comment: Please show us an example of inital image, rotated by 45 and what you want at 90 degrees.

Comment: Thanks @GBouffard. I've now added a simplified version of my code. I hope that helps a bit.

Comment: @MBo I've added a code example now. At 90 degrees, I would cap it with a Math.min(magicScaleFormular) to match the width of the canvas. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Yes, this scale is `1/cos(angle)`  (1,414 for angle 45) and becomes infinite near 90 degrees. You can limit scaleY by screensize/imagesize to avoid singularity.

Comment: @MBo that is absolutely brilliant, thanks. I feel a lot more stupid now, but at least I can get on with my life now. I made this jsFiddle where your answer is implemented: https://jsfiddle.net/waaentz/htrqdwjp/15/ 

Can you write is as an answer so I can accept it as the right answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scale is `1.0/cos(angle)` (1,414 for angle 45) and becomes infinite near 90 degrees.

It is worth to limit scale by max value like this:  (I added 0.3 to see all picture in the fiddle window at 88 degrees)

```
 magicScaleFormular = Math.min(0.3 * canvas.width / img.width, 
                               1 / Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180))
```