# How do I find x of where my rotated image touches a top-line

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, html5-canvas

See problem illustrated here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuy8c.png

I have an image rotated based on an angle, and stretched to match both bottom and top line. 
My question is: How do I find X of where the image touches the top line.

JsFiddle with an example http://jsfiddle.net/waaentz/htrqdwjp/43/

X is (faulty) calculated on line 28

```
let angle = 0; // Is dynamic

const width = 500;
const height = 100;
const padding = 100;
const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
const stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
const img = new Image();
const bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(img);
const baseGrid = new createjs.Shape();
const point = new createjs.Shape();

// Update angle each 30ms
setInterval(()=>{
  if (angle++ > 90) angle = 0;
  draw();
}, 30)

// Draw when image is loaded (arrow image)
img.src = getBase64();
img.addEventListener("load", ()=>{
    draw();
});

// Draw function
function draw(){
  const magicScaleFormular = 1 / Math.cos(angle * Math.PI / 180) 
  const magicXFormular = width - (width / magicScaleFormular); // <-- X formular

    stage.y = padding;
    stage.addChild(baseGrid, bitmap, point);
    Object.assign(canvas, {width, height: height + (padding * 2)});

    bitmap.regX = (img.width / 2);
    bitmap.regY = img.height;
    bitmap.y = height;
    bitmap.rotation = angle;
    bitmap.scaleY = magicScaleFormular; 

  point.graphics.clear()
    .beginFill("red")
    .drawCircle(0,0,10);

  point.x = magicXFormular;

    baseGrid.graphics
        .beginStroke("red")
        .setStrokeStyle(4)
        .moveTo(0,0)
        .lineTo(width, 0)
        .moveTo(0, height)
        .lineTo(width, height)

    stage.update();
    document.body.append(canvas);
}
```

This question is related to this: [Finding size of rotated image to match top-line based on angle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58720069/finding-size-of-rotated-image-to-match-top-line-based-on-angle)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To calculate one cathetus of triangle using another one, you need tangent

```
const magicXFormular = 100 * Math.tan(angle * Math.PI / 180);
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! Thanks a lot. I appreciate your time highly! This really helps me out. I've updated the Fiddle here for anyone else to see: http://jsfiddle.net/waaentz/htrqdwjp/47/

Comment: Don't forget to change 100 to appropriate variable/constant